# How to create an array of times from in jquery with one hour interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched around a lot, and found some examples, but non of those did not work as expected. I am trying to create available time slots to specific day and would like to display times like this:

10.00   | available

11.00   | available

12-00   | available

13.00   | available

etc.

For example right now start times at 16.00 (current time in my timezone UTC+02:00), rest of the times should be disabled. Then tomorrow start from 00.00 again. How should I make that work?

What I have right now is this:

```
var arr = [], i, j;
for(i=0; i<24; i++) {
  for(j=0; j<1; j++) {
    arr.push(i + ":" + ("00") );
  }
}

var d = new Date(),
    h = d.getHours(),
    m = 15 * Math.floor(d.getMinutes() / 15),
    stamp = h + ":" + (m === 0 ? "00" : m);

var pos = arr.indexOf(stamp),
    timelist = arr.slice(pos).concat(arr.slice(0, pos));

console.log(arr);
```

which gives me this

```
["0:00", "1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", "5:00", "6:00", "7:00", "8:00", "9:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"]
```

### EDIT

I thought instead of creating a new question I would elaborate on this.
Would it be possible to display the time slots like this:

10.00 - 11.00  | available

12.00 - 13.00  | available

13-00 - 14.00  | available

15.00 - 16.00  | available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cut the array, instead get the actual hour and change your for loop:

```js
var date = new Date;
var hour = date.getHours();

var arr = [];
for(var i=hour; i<24; i++) {
  arr.push(i + ":00") );
}
console.log(arr);
```

If you want to show the past times as well, why not make two arrays:

```js
var date = new Date;
var hour = date.getHours();

var pastHours = [],
    futureHours = [];
for( var i=0; i<hour; i++ ) {
  pastHours.push(i+":00");
}
for(var i=hour; i<24; i++) {
  futureHours.push(i + ":" + ("00") );
}
console.log(pastHours);
console.log(futureHours);
```

Or in one array:

```js
var arr = [];
for( var i=0; i<24; i++ ) {
  arr.push(i+":00");
}

var date = new Date,
    hour = date.getHours(),
    hourIndex = arr.indexOf(hour+":00");

var pastHours = arr.slice(0,hourIndex);
var futureHours = arr.slice(hourIndex);

console.log(pastHours);
console.log(futureHours);
```

Comment: Is there any way to show the past times as well but disable them? like grey them out.

Comment: No problem, I've added a third alternativ... :)

Comment: That is even better bro! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
var d=new Date();
i=d.getHours();
times=[];
while(i<24){
times.push("today "+i+":00 available");
i++;
}
```

times doesnow contain 15 to 24 as a string. you can use your loop to add additional dates

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach. It will put hours in array for the said interval from now, excluding hours between those in *disabled* array.

```
var interval = 24 //hours
var disabled = [4, 16];
var date = new Date();
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < interval; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + 60*60*1000*i);
    console.log(newDate.getHours())
  if(newDate.getHours() < disabled[0] || newDate.getHours() > disabled[1]) {
    arr.push(newDate.getHours())
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```